# Recovery the previous Ubuntu behavior for typing accents

Tags: keyboard

In the lastest Ubuntu (20.04+) when I'm typing accents in Spanish, they are working as in MacOS:

[image]

I'm not comfortable with this behavior. Is possible to work with accents as in any previous Ubuntu releases and any Windows OS?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what keyboard layout are you using?  Do you have those characters on the keyboard? The ones on the bottom I tend to type using ALT with 3 digits on a standard US kbd ;)  would the RightAlt method be a alternative? (US International dead keys does that: ñ= RightAlt + n
Ñ = RightAlt + n + Shift

Comment: Spanish layout. An accent is clicking ´ and then the vowel. As in any OS.

Comment: look here, in Latvian with apostrophe it's still working like that. See /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv at `partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys`, it has this `ISO_Level3_Latch`, make something like that for your own custom Spanish layout

Comment: Hi, but I don't find those lines in my language file:
costales@hp:~$ grep ISO_Level3_Latch /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es
costales@hp:~$ grep modifier_keys /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es
costales@hp:~$

Comment: it was just an idea that you could try to make your **custom** Spanish layout. And, please, use this @ to address someone you want he/she gets notified.